# Javascript function is not being called from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

I have a javascript function like

```
function CloseWindow() {
    alert("I am firing");    // window.close();         
}
```

I am trying to call it from code behind button click event like

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "Javascript", "javascript:CloseWindow();", True)
```

The function is not firing alert message.
 **If I call the same function from OnClientClick it is firing.**

```
OnClientClick="javascript:();"
```

What might be the cause? If you want anymore clarification, please let me know.

by `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function CloseWindow() {
            alert("I am firing");
//            window.close();

        }
        function chkLength(evt, len) {
            var str = document.getElementById(evt.id);
            if (str.value.length < len)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    </script>`

Comment: Can you provide the code surrounding the javascript code?

Comment: I tagged with VB.Net, everyone is answering in c# :(

Comment: @Johan Check my Script section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you Used Update Panels Then You can Use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "javascriptFunction();", true);
```

Other Wise You can Use

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
        (GetType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "javascriptFunction();",true);
```

Answer (score 2):

try the below code....

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
        (GetType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "javascript: CloseWindow();",true);
```

Comment: Is it `true` in VB.Net or `True`?

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter (script) must be "CloseWindow();" and not "javascript:CloseWindow();"

Comment: Be sure that the function "CloseWindow" is declared at the very top of your html page.